# How should I typeset the names of the TeXbook and the METAFONTbook?

Tags: citing, metafont, logos

I want to refer to both the TeX book and the Metafont book in a document that I am writing.  My attempt at typesetting the TeX book looks ok, but the other one is a bit of a disaster.  Can anyone suggest a better approach?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mflogo}
\begin{document}
\noindent
This looks fine in slanted text: \textsl{The \TeX book}, I am happy with this one.

\smallskip\noindent
But this is not so good: \textsl{The \MF book}; apart from the sans v serif issues,
the caps height in the logo does not match the ascender of the “b” and the slant
angles differ.  Even if I add a little space: \textsl{The \MF\thinspace book} it
still looks odd.  And this looks too shouty: \textsl{The METAFONTbook}.  What about
\textsl{\sffamily The \MF book}?  No, the sans font is no better.  And let's pass
over \textsl{\logofamily The METAFONTbook}.  Perhaps \textsl{The MetaFontBook}?
Any other suggestions?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you require `\textsl`?  The `mflogo` package typesets the `The METAFONTbook` example using `\textit` [(on page 1, section 2)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mflogo/mflogo.pdf).  The baseline for `\textit{The \MF{}book}` and `\textit{The \MF{}\sffamily book}` seems to line up for me.  Admittedly, the slants are a bit different...you may want to consider using the same font that \MF uses for `The` and `book`.

Comment: Oops, after looking closely at the font, it seems the MetaFont font only supports capital letters.  It may require either careful font choice to match the slant or a manual slant change.

Comment: I'd simply avoid slanted type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source for the actual book (`mfbook.tex`), Knuth uses

```
{\titlefont The {\manual ()*+,-.*}book}
```

for the title, but that doesn't help you with regular text. (Elsewhere it's simply "The METAFONTbook" -- no special font or italics -- but that's in `tt` and other environments where no formatting is expected.)

In his errata files, he uses

```
{\sl The \slMF\kern1ptbook\/}
```

which is probably what you want:

[image: from errata.six]

In `mf.web`, he uses

```
{\sl The {\logos METAFONT\/}book}
```

which looks like this:

[image: mf.web screenshot]

Actually, in The METAFONTbook he also uses (at the end of Appendix A)

```
{\sl The %
 {\manual \char`\\]\char`\^\char`\_efg\char`\^}\kern1ptbook\/}
```

which is probably the same as the former.

Incidentally in `gftype.web` and `gftopk.web` there is:

```
\font\tenss=cmss10 % for `The METAFONTbook'
```

suggesting using the Computer Modern Sans Serif font, but then that does not seem to be actually used.

Comment: For completeness: `\def\slMF{{\manual 89:;}\-{\manual <=>:}} % slant the logo`

Comment: The TeXbook of course is simply `{\sl The \TeX book}`, which can also be written (after `\def\TEX/{\TeX}`) as `{\sl The \TEX/book}` or `{\sl The \TEX/book\/}` depending on the next character.

Comment: (BTW: Is it just my eyes, or does the baseline of "METAFONT" appear lower than the rest of the text in the above examples? Not sure whether that's an artefact of the PDF rendering or what...)